# U-blox Neo-6M GPS module and RX LED of Arduino aren't blinking

Tags: arduino-uno

I started recently working with a uBlox Neo 6M GPS module.
Connection between Arduino and GPS module....

```
Vcc pin --> 3.3V , 
Tx pin --> D2, 
Rx pin --> D3, 
Gnd --> Gnd
```

I tried with this code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
// Choose two Arduino pins to use for software serial
int RXPin = 2;
int TXPin = 3;
//Default baud of NEO-6M is 9600
int GPSBaud = 9600;
// Create a software serial port called "gpsSerial"
SoftwareSerial gpsSerial(RXPin, TXPin);
void setup()
{
  // Start the Arduino hardware serial port at 9600 baud
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Start the software serial port at the GPS's default baud
  gpsSerial.begin(GPSBaud);
}
void loop()
{
  // Displays information when new sentence is available.
  while (gpsSerial.available() > 0)
    Serial.write(gpsSerial.read());
}
```

About 2-3 hours, I was working with it.. But I do not get the GPS LED to blink, as well as my Arduino's RX LED. In serial monitor I didn't get any data. Is my gps module destroyed??

Comment: Are you indoor or outdoor?

Comment: your code is missing the part that sends data from the Serial to gpsSerial ... the NEO-6M gets no data

Comment: Are you sure your module will run on 3.3v ?  Some modules need 5v to run while some work on 3.3v.  Also, what Arduino board do you have ?  Most have 5v logic level pins. You must ensure that the logic level matches between module and arduino.